# openSUSE hanging on boot

Tags: linux, boot, virtualbox, opensuse

I just installed openSUSE Tumbleweed with a clean install in VirtualBox. On boot it hangs after the line

```
[ OK ] Started Accounts Service....2.ons service....ns kernel modules.f8fe71.
```

(Actually I think that may be multiple lines somehow overwriting each other.)

I tried to search for a solution on-line, and I got numerous results, [even for other Linux distros having similar problems](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=47928). But most of them are mostly about [changes in an already running system](https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/488751-Fresh-12-3-bumped-to-TW-hangs-on-boot), which can't be my case this is very a fresh install, the paint is still wet. Also NVidia drivers are also often mentioned which I don't think are quite relevant for a VirtualBox virtual machine.

The strangest part is that I can choose the special settings from GRUB (I don't know how they are actually special), with which the system starts up fine.

I tried to do a `zypper dup`, which was also often mentioned as a solution, but it didn't help.

The question is: how can I find out what's wrong here, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried to install guest additions after booting via the alternate (failsafe?) GRUB option?

Comment: Guest additions are installed by default.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.  As I don't have any handy suse VM around for testing please try the following; assuming FailSafe works, just try to create a new entry on grub to have those failsafe extra arguments (like apm=off, acpi=off,etc) and by elimination you should be able to find the offending argument(s) then we can proceed further on the troubleshooting.

Comment: I tried to add a new entry, I looked into some files in `/etc/grub.d/`. Well... I can't even find which one is the failsafe one.

Comment: In my past experience opensuse used the good old /boot/grub/menu.lst.  But now it is not applicable, just google for "modify grub2 menu" and you will find tons of information.  Just remember to update grub after each modification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why this was relevant, but:

In `/boot/grub2/grub.cfg` I needed to change the parameter

```
resume=/dev/sda1
```

(the current Tumbleweed way) to

```
resume=/dev/disk/by-uuid/[put your own UUID here for sda1]
```

as used in Leap. And after that the boot finished successfully.

Answer (score 2):

Have the same problem, solution above don't work for me (already uuid used)
My solution was change in grub's kernel options

```
quiet splash=silent resume=/dev/disk/by-uuid/479297bf-8f35-4c4c-8bc1-d1c19f9ce6fc splash=silent quiet showopts
```

to

```
quiet resume=/dev/disk/by-uuid/479297bf-8f35-4c4c-8bc1-d1c19f9ce6fc quiet
```